# Split PostgreSQL table column values into multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

I am working with PostgreSQL and I have a table with 2 columns `manager_id` and `manager_name`. I want to split `manager_name` column (with values such as: ANGLO EASTERN SHIPMANAGEMENT - HONG KONG, CHINA) to Manager name| city | country. delimiter "-"and "," .

[image: database table]

I tried this query but it just show the result, not saved that columns permanently

```
select 
    manager_name,
    split_part(manager_name, '-', 1) m_name,
    split_part(manager_name, ',', 2) city,
    split_part(manager_name, ',', 2) country 
from 
    manager2
```

Is there any other way to split this column and saved it in that table permanently ??

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: For tables that are data use initilization code with code block format. For other tables there is a table format. Posts here are for forever & for many later visitors, please always edit posts to the best they can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a bit verbose, but the following seems to do it. Your `SPLIT_PART()` to retrieve the city from `manager_name` needed some tweaking; also wrap them in `TRIM()` to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
CREATE TABLE manager2
(
  manager_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  manager_name VARCHAR(250)
);

INSERT INTO manager2 (manager_name)
VALUES ('ANGLO EASTERN SHIPMANAGEMENT - HONG KONG, CHINA');
INSERT INTO manager2 (manager_name)
VALUES ('HARTMANN REEDEREI - LEER, GERMANY');

-- add columns to table
ALTER TABLE manager2 ADD COLUMN m_name VARCHAR(250);
ALTER TABLE manager2 ADD COLUMN city VARCHAR(250);
ALTER TABLE manager2 ADD COLUMN country VARCHAR(250);

-- populate tables with vals
WITH results AS (
  SELECT manager_id AS id, TRIM(SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 1)) AS m_name, 
  TRIM(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 2), ',', 1)) AS city,  
  TRIM(SPLIT_PART(manager_name, ',', 2)) AS country
  FROM manager2
  )
UPDATE manager2
SET 
m_name = (SELECT m_name FROM results WHERE manager_id = results.id),
city = (SELECT city FROM results WHERE manager_id = results.id),
country = (SELECT country FROM results WHERE manager_id = results.id);
```

Table after update:

```
 manager_id |                  manager_name                   |            m_name            |   city    | country
------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------+---------
          1 | ANGLO EASTERN SHIPMANAGEMENT - HONG KONG, CHINA | ANGLO EASTERN SHIPMANAGEMENT | HONG KONG | CHINA
          2 | HARTMANN REEDEREI - LEER, GERMANY               | HARTMANN REEDEREI            | LEER      | GERMANY
```

---

Update to handle cases like 'PSA - SINGAPORE' as `PSA | NULL | SINGAPORE`. Instead of the CTE used above (`WITH results AS (...)`), you could use the following code:

```
WITH results AS (
  SELECT manager_id AS id, TRIM(SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 1)) AS m_name,
    CASE
      WHEN SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 2) ~ ',' THEN
        TRIM(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 2), ',', 1))
      ELSE
        NULL
    END AS city,
    CASE 
      WHEN SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 2) ~ ',' THEN 
        TRIM(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 2), ',', 2)) 
      ELSE
        TRIM(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 2), ',', 1)) 
    END AS country
  FROM manager2
  )
```

Result:

```
 manager_id |                  manager_name                   |            m_name            |   city    |  country
------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------+-----------
          1 | ANGLO EASTERN SHIPMANAGEMENT - HONG KONG, CHINA | ANGLO EASTERN SHIPMANAGEMENT | HONG KONG | CHINA
          2 | HARTMANN REEDEREI - LEER, GERMANY               | HARTMANN REEDEREI            | LEER      | GERMANY
          3 | PSA - SINGAPORE                                 | PSA                          |           | SINGAPORE
```

Comment: It worked!!! but in some rows I see country names  in city column maybe because of delimiter on wrong place which i need to solve manually i guess , but its more then 30,000 rows, its mean really hard.

Comment: Could you give an example of a string in `manager_name` that doesn't split as expected?

Comment: I have manger_name such as 'PSA - SINGAPORE' which take PSA as name and Singapore as city, whereas SINGAPORE is country name. also 'TITA - PANAMA' ..

Comment: To handle cases like 'PSA - SINGAPORE', instead of `TRIM(SPLIT_PART(manager_name, ',', 2)) AS country`, you could use: `CASE WHEN SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 2) ~ ',' THEN TRIM(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 2), ',', 2)) ELSE NULL END AS country`. This will check whether the part beyond '-' has a comma. If so: split `city, country`, else only populate `city` and leave `country` empty.

Comment: yeah i replace that line but just give me null in all 3 columns.  CASE WHEN SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 2) ~ ',' THEN TRIM(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', 2), ',', 2)) ELSE NULL END AS country

Comment: Added update. Ignore previous suggestion here in the comments.

Comment: Thanks it work but small another problem , it miss the manager_ name such as 'NAVARONE MARINE ENTERPRISE ATHENS, GREECE', 'SOUTHERN SHIPMANAGEMENT VALPARAISO, CHILE' and 'X-PRESS FEEDERS' take PRESS FEEDERS as country name.

Comment: If you have many exceptions, I'd suggest you first map all patterns (and supply examples), and then turn to (rather more complex) regex for filtering. At that stage, if you experience difficulties, open up a new Q here on SO. But not sure if you could handle all this variation. How would we capture `city` for 'COMPANY - IN BUSINESS HONG KONG, CHINA'? Apparently possible. If you only have a few exceptions, I'd update manually. Either way, I'd start with a `GROUP BY` on country with `COUNT()` in `ASC` order. I'd expect the erroneous "countries" to turn up on top. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways I know. You can use the SPLIT_PART and ALTER TABLE or the CREATE VIEW statement to store the query permanently inside another table. Then use the table as your primary table

```
  --The ALTER TABLE 
  SELECT *,
   SPLIT_PART(manager_name,'-',1) AS manager_name1, 
   SPLIT_PART(manager_name,',',2) AS city,
   SPLIT_PART(manager_name,',',3) AS country
   FROM table_name;
   
  -- NOW lets update the table

  ALTER TABLE table_name 
  ADD manager_name1 varchar(500);
  UPDATE manager_name1 
  SET manager_name1 = SPLIT_PART(manager_name,'-',1);

  ALTER TABLE table_name 
  ADD city varchar(500);
  UPDATE city 
  SET city = SPLIT_PART(manager_name,',',2);

  ALTER TABLE table_name 
  ADD country varchar(500);
  UPDATE country 
  SET country = SPLIT_PART(manager_name,',',3);
```

The Create View

```
CREATE VIEW new_table_name AS
SELECT SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', '1') AS manager_name1,
SPLIT_PART(manager_name, '-', '2') AS city
SPLIT_PART(manager_name, ',', '3') AS country;
```

Three columns will be created in your view, then you can drop the original manager_name that you split.